# Group Specific Rows within Group By

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking to combine some specific values in an aggregation query after the group by clause. If I have to hard code in that these specific examples need to be grouped, that should be ok.

So after the group by, we have sales by person which I would like to get to the lower image

[image: Group in Group]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when salesperson in ('Luke', 'Bob', 'Luke/Bob') then 'Luke/Bob'
             else salesperson
        end) as salesperson,
       sum(sales)
from t
group by (case when salesperson in ('Luke', 'Bob', 'Luke/Bob') then 'Luke/Bob'
               else salesperson
          end);
```